# Bootstrap modal not working on iOS - shows only grey background

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I made a website with Laravel. For design of web site I use Bootstrap. In on my page I needed modal component. Now I deployed my web site on server [link on website](http://178.128.250.49/rang-liste/piramida/1) and I was testing website with my iPhone. When I tested modal I get only grey background without modal. I also tested on PC and Android mobile phone and work fine. I try on Edge, Safari and Chrome on iPhone but I always get the same result.

Here is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.frontend')
@section('title', 'TK Pazin | Rang-liste Piramida')
@section('content')
 <!-- Page Content -->
 <div class="container">
 <!-- Page Heading -->
 <h1 class="my-4" style="text-align:center; color: #ba3631;">Rang-lista | Piramida {{ $sezona->godina }}</h1>
 <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
    @foreach($sezone as $sezona)
        @if($sezona->id == session('odabrana_godina'))
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{ $sezona->godina }}</li>
        @else
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('ranglista.piramida.kola', $sezona->id) }}">{{ $sezona->godina }}</a></li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </ol>
</nav>
<div>
    <div class="media mb-5">
        <div class="mr-3"><a href="../datoteke/Pravila-Pojedinačni-turniri.pdf" target="_blank"><i
            class="far fa-file-pdf fa-3x"></i></a></div>
        <div class="media-body mt-3">
            <a href="/datoteke/Pravila-Piramida.pdf" target="_blank">
            <h5 class="mt-0">Pravila
                natjecanja u piramidi
            </h5>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Ime i prezime</th>
            @foreach($kola as $kolo)
                <th scope="col">{{ $kolo->naziv }}</th>
            @endforeach
            <th scope="col">Ukupno</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($igraci as $igrac)
            @if($igrac->igrac_piramida()->whereIn('turnir_piramida_id', $kola_id)->sum('bodovi') != 0)
            <tr>
                <td scope="row" class="sno">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_{{ $igrac->id }}">{{ $igrac->ime . " " . $igrac->prezime }}</button>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="view_{{ $igrac->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Natjecatelj: {{ $igrac->ime . " " . $igrac->prezime }}</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="{{ $igrac->slika }}" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <b>Prebivalište: </b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->prebivaliste }}</p>
                                        <b>Igra: </b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->igra }}</p>
                                        <b>Član kluba od:</b>
                                        <p> {{ $igrac->clanstvo }}. godine</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                    @foreach($kola as $kolo)
                        @foreach($igrac->igrac_piramida as $ip)
                            @if($ip->pivot->turnir_piramida_id == $kolo->id)
                                <td>{{ $ip->pivot->bodovi }}</td>

                            @endif

                        @endforeach

                    @endforeach
                    <td>{{ $igrac->igrac_piramida()->whereIn('turnir_piramida_id', $kola_id)->sum('bodovi') }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endif
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
@endsection
@section('script')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //use a special class name or id for the table
        //using find I'm getting all tr elements in the table
        //using not(':eq(0)') I'm ignoring the first tr element
        //using each I'm iterating through the selected elements
        $('table').find('tr').not(':eq(0)').each(function(i){
            //using children('td:eq(0)') I'm getting the first td element inside the tr
            $(this).children('td:eq(0)').addClass('sno').text(i+1);
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Change your bootstrap cdn and take a look

Comment: I changed to newest version and nothing is changed